# Framework not found on restarting the xcode ot reopening the project

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I have facing this issue from last two days. Every time I restart the xcode or i close the project and reopen it, some of the frameworks give error i.e **NewRelic**. I remove the references and again import it and its working but have to do this tedious work every time.

What is the issue in my code or xcode.

**EDIT:** Here are snapshots of error:

[image]

Framework in build phase:

[image]

Comment: Please provide more info.  Where are these frameworks in relation to your project.  Show some screenshots of the Xcode project configuration and error messages.

Comment: I have imported my frameworks in .pch file. Error says undefined symbol

Comment: Wouldn't you normally import Frameworks within the *Link Libraries* section of the Target build configuration?

Comment: OK, have you set the *Header Search* path correctly?

Comment: Yes I have checked it as well and the thing is that all frameworks are woking fine except this one. If problem was due to path, then it should give errors for others as well.

Comment: Not true; unless you've set *Search Recursively* as each framework has its own `Headers` directory.

Answer (score 2):

The answer here...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25009037/1071320

... solved the issue for me. If any of the parent folders in which your framework is contained contain spaces, Xcode is going to get very confused!

Answer (score 1):

This is xcode project subfolder issue

In xCode Project name is "My ABCApp"
goto -> My ABCApp -> TARGETS -> My ABCApp -> Build Settings -> "Framework Search Path"

Replace
From
$(PROJECT_DIR)/My
ABCApp/Library/xxx.framework

To

$(PROJECT_DIR)/My\ ABCApp/Library/xxx.framework

Good Luck :)