# Library Not Found after Restarting Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am using latest Xcode 5.1.1.

When I make a new project and import chartboost for example or revmob everything works fine. But when I close Xcode and re-open it this is what I get:

[image]

As far as I understand there is an issue with the library search paths.

I have tried to delete everything from library search paths -> Not working
Delete the derived data from Organizer -> Not Working

When I delete the libraries and re-import it works great until I restart again Xcode.

I appreciate your help.

Better screenshot: 
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those who are interested, it turned out that the error comes when you drag and drop a folder in the project that contains a subfolder with a space in its name. Then XCode Library Search Paths are not correct, because the path to a framework is separated in 2 lines. For example if you have a folder "ParentFolder/Child Folder/Framework1" then the library search path will look like this:

- $(SRCROOT)/ParentFolder/Child
- Folder/Framework1

instead of this:

- $(SRCROOT)/ParentFolder/Child\ Folder/Framework1

It is a very annoying bug in XCode, which cost us several hours to fix it. We hope this solution helps someone who is frustrated with importing a framework.

Comment: WOWOWOW Thankyou! That is so weird hahaha

Comment: You save my day thank you! It's been happened to me for days